# How to get continuous number based on item number for each category in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to ask how to write a formula as below needs:

My column "X" contains a list of categories, which has different items for each category. And for column "Desired Number", I would like to get a continuous number for each category from 1. Please see blow picture.

[image]

How should I write the formula to get these continuous number automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you need is =IF(A2=A1, B1+1, 1)

You'll also need to enter the first row as 1 and 1 otherwise you'll get an error and you'll need to update it to your own columns but it then can be copied and pasted down as required.

Comment: I just found out the requirement is a little different in real case, because my B2 is not equal to 1. Is there a more common solution? Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution now - use below formula: =COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)